# .gitattributes not showing the proper language (linguist-detectable)

Tags: git, github, github-linguist

I have a project with several files. Mostly JavaScript, HTML, CSS but also Solidity. 
The project core is about Solidity, so I want Git showing as language **Solidity**.

I created `.gitattributes` and add the following:

```
*.sol linguist-detectable=true
*.html linguist-detectable=false
*.css linguist-detectable=false
*.js linguist-detectable=false
```

However, now, is appearing blank.
Anyone know what am I doing wrong or how I can fix this?

Comment: See https://github.com/github/linguist; that extension isn't in `languages.yml`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for your answer. However Solidity appears in languages.yml: 
Solidity:
  type: programming
  color: "#AA6746"
  ace_mode: text
  tm_scope: source.solidity
language_id: 237469032

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it changing the first line to `*.sol linguist-language=Solidity`
Thanks!